# Need an HTML Script For Populating Email Signatures in Outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook, exchange-server, gpo

I have had no luck using/finding a script that will create an email signature in outlook for each employee in our company.

I have tired to create a signature via Exchange ECP that pull AD information for each employee but the signature is always populating at the very end of the email string and never shows in drafts or sent mail.

Using a 3rd party program like CodeTwo is not an option.

below is the HTML code I have used in ECP, it is the exact parameters I need I just cannot execute:

```
</br>
</br>
<div style="font-size:11pt;  font-family: 'Calibri',sans-serif;">
<b>%%displayname%%</b></br>
%%title%%, %%company%%</br>
%%street%%, %%city%%, %%state%% %%zipcode%%</br>
Phone: %%Phone%% , Fax: %%Fax%%</br>
%%notes%%
</div>
```

I would like to have the above code populate either using AD or something else.

Environment: Exchange 2013, Server 2012 R2, mix of windows 7 and 10 workstations.